# Can I use mini-DP to DVI adapter on MacBook Pro mid 2012 (Thunderbolt 1) to connect to my monitor?

Tags: macbook-pro, dvi, thunderbolt, mini-displayport

I have MacBook Pro (Mid 2012), which has Thunderbolt 1, I want to connect it to my monitor (HP Pro Display P221).

Then a Thunderbolt to DVI adapter is required, but I can't find any adapter to do this only mini display to DVI is available.

It's possible to use mini-display to DVI adapter on Thunderbolt 1 port? does it transfer audio and video or just video?

As I see mini-display and Thunderbolt both have same shape and design.

How is possible to make it work for my situation?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am replying to an old thread but get a Tripp Lite-branded adapter.

- I have successfully used every single port of [this adapter (Keyspan Mini DisplayPort to VGA/DVI/HDMI All-in-One Adapter Video Converter, Black, 6 in.; P137-06N-HDV)](https://tripplite.eaton.com/adapter-converter-displayport-vga-dvi-hdmi-6-inch%7EP13706NHDV) to connect Dell, HP, and even TVs to MBP (2011/2012 retina, etc), iMac, and Mac minis (2012 and others) both running Linux and OSX without issues. In fact, this is my to-go connector when the computer has a mini display/Thunderbolt 1/2 port. It never ever let me down.
- I also have used [this adapter (Keyspan Mini DisplayPort to Active VGA Adapter, Video Converter, DP1.2, (M/F), White, 6-in. (15.24 cm); P137-06N-VGAV2)](https://tripplite.eaton.com/mini-displayport-1.2-to-vga-adapter-converter-mini-dp-male-to-vga-female-6-inch-chromebook-microsoft-surface%7EP13706NVGAV2) for my VGA needs (no luck with [a similarly named (older?) adapter (Keyspan Mini DisplayPort to Active VGA Adapter, Video Converter (M/F), White, 6-in. (15.24 cm); P137-06N-VGA)](https://tripplite.eaton.com/mini-displayport-male-to-vga-female-video-adapter%7EP13706NVGA) though, at least not through Amazon) for my VGA needs because I wanted to save the multiport one for special occasions like diagnosing.
- I have not tried their DVI-only adapter, but based on previous results I do not see why it would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbolt outputs are backwards comptabile with mini displayport adapters.  The opposite is not true though (you can't use Thunderbolt adapter in a Mini DisplayPort).

DVI does not carry audio.

- [What You Need to Know About Thunderbolt 1&2 vs Mini DisplayPort](https://blog.startech.com/post/what-you-need-to-know-about-thunderbolt-vs-mini-displayport/)